# Twilio whatsapp REST API Call from OIC giving this error 400, Postman calls works fine

Tags: oracle, twilio, cloud, integration, whatsapp

```
Error
Error message is - com.oracle.bpel.client.BPELFault: faultName: {{http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/PostMessage_REQUEST}APIInvocationError}
parts: {{
null=<soap-env:Fault xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><faultcode xmlns:faultsrc="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/PostMessage_REQUEST">faultsrc:APIInvocationError</faultcode><faultstring>ICS runtime execution error</faultstring><detail><ICSfaultVar>
<ns2:APIInvocationError xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/generic/rest/fault/REST/PostMessage"><ns2:type/><ns2:title/><ns2:detail/><ns2:errorCode/><ns2:errorDetails><ns2:type>http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1</ns2:type><ns2:title>Bad Request</ns2:title><ns2:errorCode>400</ns2:errorCode><ns2:errorPath><![CDATA[POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages.json%7BFrom%7D%7BTo%7D%7BBody%7D?To=whatsapp:+971501264905&From=whatsapp:+14155238886&Body=Approved-Absence-Dated_30-Nov-2020_To_01-Dec-2020 returned a response status of 400 Bad Request]]></ns2:errorPath><ns2:instance><![CDATA[<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<TwilioResponse><RestException><Code>21604</Code><Message>A 'To' phone number is required.</Message><MoreInfo>https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21604</MoreInfo><Status>400</Status></RestException></TwilioResponse>.A 400 Bad Request Error indicates that the target service is unable (or refuses) to process the request sent by the client (Oracle Integration Cloud), due to an issue that is perceived by the server to be a client problem. You can trace the cURL representation of the request sent to the target service from the Oracle Integration Cloud server logs. Try invoking the target service using cURL. It may also be that one of the intermediaries (proxy, LBR) could be returning this code. ]]></ns2:instance></ns2:errorDetails></ns2:APIInvocationError></ICSfaultVar><reason>Fault Details :
<ns2:APIInvocationError xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/generic/rest/fault/REST/PostMessage"><ns2:type/><ns2:title/><ns2:detail/><ns2:errorCode/><ns2:errorDetails><ns2:type>http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1</ns2:type><ns2:title>Bad Request</ns2:title><ns2:errorCode>400</ns2:errorCode><ns2:errorPath>&lt;![CDATA[POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages.json%7BFrom%7D%7BTo%7D%7BBody%7D?To=whatsapp:+971501264905&amp;From=whatsapp:+14155238886&amp;Body=Approved-Absence-Dated_30-Nov-2020_To_01-Dec-2020 returned a response status of 400 Bad Request]]&gt;</ns2:errorPath><ns2:instance>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?&gt;
&lt;TwilioResponse&gt;&lt;RestException&gt;&lt;Code&gt;21604&lt;/Code&gt;&lt;Message&gt;A 'To' phone number is required.&lt;/Message&gt;&lt;MoreInfo&gt;https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21604&lt;/MoreInfo&gt;&lt;Status&gt;400&lt;/Status&gt;&lt;/RestException&gt;&lt;/TwilioResponse&gt;.A 400 Bad Request Error indicates that the target service is unable (or refuses) to process the request sent by the client (Oracle Integration Cloud), due to an issue that is perceived by the server to be a client problem. You can trace the cURL representation of the request sent to the target service from the Oracle Integration Cloud server logs. Try invoking the target service using cURL. It may also be that one of the intermediaries (proxy, LBR) could be ret:Application Error</reason><operation>execute</operation></detail></soap-env:Fault>}
cause: {null}
Parallel For-Each Failed
```

What changes should be done to make the REST API Call work, apparatly all information here is relevant AccountId:Authtoken is not showing here in the debugging call

can you please point out the issue.

AR

Answer (score 0):

Reading the error message, `A 'To' phone number is required.`.

Please make he request using the `x-www-form-urlencoded` format (not JSON).

[Make a Write Request to an External API using urlencoded data](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/serverless-functions-make-a-write-request-to-an-external-api-urlencoded)